# How to integrate a speech function in kotlin to read out objects being detected

Tags: kotlin, text-to-speech

I have a code for a tensorflow object detector api and i want the objects being detected to be read aloud. The objects being labled are called result.categories[0].label.

Here is the function that defines them, the result.categories[0].score is for the confidence rating:

```
val drawableText =
                result.categories[0].label + " " +
                        String.format("%.2f", result.categories[0].score)
```

---

Below is the code for the part of the app that has this function, called Overlayview.kt

---

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.Detection
import java.util.LinkedList
import kotlin.math.max



class OverlayView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {


    private var results: List<Detection> = LinkedList<Detection>()
    private var boxPaint = Paint()
    private var textBackgroundPaint = Paint()
    private var textPaint = Paint()

    private var scaleFactor: Float = 1f

    private var bounds = Rect()



    fun clear() {
        textPaint.reset()
        textBackgroundPaint.reset()
        boxPaint.reset()
        invalidate()
        initPaints()
    }


    private fun initPaints() {
        textBackgroundPaint.color = Color.BLACK
        textBackgroundPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        textBackgroundPaint.textSize = 50f

        textPaint.color = Color.WHITE
        textPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        textPaint.textSize = 50f

        boxPaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.bounding_box_color)
        boxPaint.strokeWidth = 8F
        boxPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)

        for (result in results) {
            val boundingBox = result.boundingBox

            val top = boundingBox.top * scaleFactor
            val bottom = boundingBox.bottom * scaleFactor
            val left = boundingBox.left * scaleFactor
            val right = boundingBox.right * scaleFactor

            // Draw bounding box around detected objects
            val drawableRect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
            canvas.drawRect(drawableRect, boxPaint)

            // Create text to display alongside detected objects
            val drawableText =
                result.categories[0].label + " " +
                        String.format("%.2f", result.categories[0].score)

          // Draw rect behind display text
            textBackgroundPaint.getTextBounds(drawableText, 0, drawableText.length, bounds)
            val textWidth = bounds.width()
            val textHeight = bounds.height()
            canvas.drawRect(
                left,
                top,
                left + textWidth + Companion.BOUNDING_RECT_TEXT_PADDING,
                top + textHeight + Companion.BOUNDING_RECT_TEXT_PADDING,
                textBackgroundPaint
            )

            // Draw text for detected object
            canvas.drawText(drawableText, left, top + bounds.height(), textPaint)
        }
    }

    fun setResults(
      detectionResults: MutableList<Detection>,
      imageHeight: Int,
      imageWidth: Int,
    ) {
        results = detectionResults

        // PreviewView is in FILL_START mode. So we need to scale up the bounding box to match with
        // the size that the captured images will be displayed.
        scaleFactor = max(width * 1f / imageWidth, height * 1f / imageHeight)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BOUNDING_RECT_TEXT_PADDING = 8
    }

}
```

I tried to set up tts initializers and then connect them to the code, but each time a new error pops up. I am more familiar in java and this kotlin code seems to be a bit trickier. I am unable to set a listener for the texttospeech because I have no idea what to set it with, as i dont want the function to be called with a button, i want the app to continuously be reading out the objects being detected.